# global file handle

Tags: perl, file

I need to use the same file handle in several perl modules. Here is my example
a.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

our $OUT_FILE_HANDLE;

require b;

open($OUT_FILE_HANDLE, ">./a.log");
print $OUT_FILE_HANDLE "text1\n";

b::f($OUT_FILE_HANDLE); // this works
```

b.pm

```
package b;

sub f($) {
  my $a = shift;
  print $a "text2\n";  // get error here
}

f($main::OUT_FILE_HANDLE);
1;
```

I get the error "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference"

If I use the handle in b.pm directly (without passing it as argument to function) it works fine

b.pm

```
package b;

sub f() {
  print $main::OUT_FILE_HANDLE "text2\n";  // this works
}

f();
1;
```

Comment: You do know that there is a core module named `B` don't you? You should avoid one-letter module names, even when testing things out. Or perhaps *especially* when testing things out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example is failing because of the order of execution: [all of b.pm is executed when you `require b;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). Thus you are trying to use the file handle before it has been opened.

As a general principle, modules should only do stuff via functions that can be called.  Only initialization things should run when the module is required.

In this case, the best design would be to use a *lexical* file handle and pass it to any function that needs it.  Don't use a global.

```
open(my $OUT_FILE_HANDLE, '>', './a.log') or die "Ouch: $!";
print $OUT_FILE_HANDLE "text1\n";

b::f($OUT_FILE_HANDLE);
```

Using globals to communicate with modules is rarely a good idea.  Occasionally it might be useful for a module to expose a global to the calling code, but the reverse is never a good design.  A module should not depend on a particular variable existing within a particular package in order to work.

Finally, you should almost never use subroutine prototypes in Perl.  Just omit the prototype, unless you know all about Perl prototypes and have a very good reason to use them:

```
sub f {
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems with your code.

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your program or right after a `package` statement
- Use `CamelCase` for package names and `snake_case` for local identifiers. People familiar with Perl will thank you
- Use something descriptive for all your identifiers. In particular there is a core package called `B` (the Perl Compiler Backend) so this won't do
- *Never* expect a subsidiary module to access data from the `main` package. The flow should be strictly bottom-upwards
- *Never* use prototypes for your subroutines. Perl is different from other languages in this respect, and prototypes do a couple of very special things. If you don't know what those things are then you certainly shouldn't be using prototypes
- Don't use `require` unless you know what it does. You almost certainly want `use`
- Use the three-parameter form of `open`, and *always* check whether it has succeeded. If an `open` failes then you should `die` with a string including `$!` to say *why* it failed

The main reason your code isn't working as you expect is that `require` (and `use`) statements will perform any executable statements in the secondary module *at the time they are included*. Normally such modules will contain only *definitions* and *declarations* for use in the calling code, and you must be very careful if you include any executable code because, as you have seen, it can cause problems with dependencies being unavailable.

Here is a working version of your code

**main.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use BB;

open my $fh, '>', 'a.log' or die $!;
print $fh "text1\n";

BB::f($fh);
```

**BB.pm**

```
package BB;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub f {
  my ($a) = @_;
  print $a "text2\n";
}

1;
```

**output** (to `a.log`)

```
text1
text2
```

Answer (score 1):

B is a bad name for a module, because it's a [Perl core module](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.3/ext/B/B.pm). Rename it with BB (for example). Also, Perl comments use '#', nor '//'. This is my modified code (that works fine):

**main.pl**

```
use BB;

our $OUT_FILE_HANDLE;
open($OUT_FILE_HANDLE, ">", "./a.log") or die $!;
print $OUT_FILE_HANDLE "text1\n";
BB::f($OUT_FILE_HANDLE);
```

**BB.pm**

```
package BB;

sub f {
  my $a = shift;
  print $a "text2\n";  
}
1;
```

Comment: I use B only for example. In my script I used other names but I still get the error

Answer (score -1):

Maybe move "our $OUT_FILE_HANDLE;" inside your b.pm package.

Comment: This is not correct. `our` is not needed at all when accessing a variable via `$package_name::variable`.

Comment: Hi dan1111. 
My answer is correct regarding the question. The question was "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference". The question was not do to her homework, thought your answer is right.

Comment: No.  "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference" is **not** caused by a lack of an `our` declaration inside the module.  The module can *see* the variable just fine; it is undefined because the variable has not been set to anything at the point the module code is executed.  Adding `our` would not change that.  It would only allow you to use `$variable` rather than `$package_name::variable` to access the variable.

Comment: Then didn't adding our + using $variable would stop the "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference" error too ?

Comment: No it won't.  You are misunderstanding "undefined".  Try this code and you will get the same error: `my $fh; print {$fh} "foo";`.  `$fh` is undefined, even though it was declared and is visible in the current scope, because it has not been set to anything.  The same is true of the OP's code, which is why `our` makes no difference to the behavior.